# I have coded for stack using arrays but whatever element I push into the stack the element is displayed as zero

Tags: data-structures

Guys I am new to this subject so please use less technical subject
    I have also attached the screenshot of the output I got.[As seen in the image the stack element displayed is 0 while I entered 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS8Vl.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#define STACK_SIZE 5
int top;
int s[5];
int item;
//for push()
void push()
{
 if(top==STACK_SIZE-1)
 {
  printf("\n stack is full, cant insert");
  return;
 }
 top=top+1;
 s[top]=item;
 printf("stck element is %d",item);
}
//pop()
int pop()
{
 if(top==-1)
 {
  return -1;
 }
 return s[top--];
}
//for display()
void display()
{
 int i;
 if(top==-1)
 {
  printf("\n stack is empty");
  return;
 }
 printf("\n Contents of stack is\n");
 for(i=0;i<=top;i++){
 printf("%d",s[i]);}
}
void main()
{
 int item;
 int item_deleted;
 int choice;
 top=-1;
 clrscr();
 for(;;)
 {
  printf("\n 1.Push 2.Pop 3.Display 4.exit");
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  switch(choice)
 {
  case 1: printf("\n enter item to be inserted");
  scanf("%d",&item);
  push();
  break;

  case 2: item_deleted=pop();
  if(item_deleted==-1)
  printf("\n stack is empty");
  else
  printf("\n item deleted=%d",item_deleted);
  break;

  case 3: display();
  break;

  case 4: exit(0);
  default: exit(0);
 }
}


}
```

I tried debugging the code but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `item` is not `item`

Comment: @Margaret Bloom I didnt get you, but what I have done there is I am using the variable item to store the value I am inserting into the stack

Comment: You got a global `item` that you are using as the value to push on the stack **and a local `item` in `main`** that you are reading the input into and that **shadows the global `item`**. The solution is simple indeed, but if you are willing to learn program it is worth **rewriting entirely** the code and take a **good** look into *function parameters** and why global vars (and impure functions) are usually a bad design choice.

Comment: Thank you @MargaretBloom that helped a lot. I came to know the mistake I made. Avoid Shadowing the global variable due to a local variable a new thing that I learnt.  I will write the same program using functions with parameters and avoid using global variables in programs I write further......